# redhawksdr Connecting multiple instances of a waveform to a device with multiple channels

Tags: c++, waveform, redhawksdr, sca

I am using Redhawk 2.0.5

I was given a Redhawk FRONTEND::TUNER device that communicates with two tuners and maps the I/Q data to a single multi-out bulkio port; with the allocationId/streamId differentiating the streams. (I have the source code so it can be modified.)

I need to connect identical SDR waveform instances so that they can use the tuner device's outputs. (I also need to connect other waveforms, but connecting a different waveform is not an issue because it will have a unique allocation ID.)

Manually I can allocate using different allocation ids .

What I need is a waveform usesdevice method OR a python code method that allows me to attach two identical waveforms to the multi-out bulkio port of the tuner device without hard coding the allocation id in the waveform's MAP file. When I try it it shows an error message something like, ALLOCATION ID ALREADY USED

There must be a way to do this but I haven't stumbled upon it yet.

- Perhaps when launching the application waveform I can pass in a unique id that can be used.
- Perhaps I can create two other dummy devices that will  break out the tuner device into two tuner devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Chapter 8](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch8.html) of the manual, specifically in section 8.1.2, "Interacting with an FEI Device with the Python Package"? There are several examples of allocating FEI devices and connecting the device to a component to ingest the allocated tuner's data.

Comment: Yes, I basically did create and  allocate the project in the way this chapter describes.